# prevent the page to post back on button click while event will work

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have written a code in VB.NET in which there are around 300 asp controls and all of them are creating dynamically with more than 6 condition per control (like `If control = dropdownlist then some code Elseif control = radiobuttonlist then some other code`).
Now I want to write events for some controls but due to postback, when event is fired all of the controls are getting flushed.

When I set `button1.onclientclick="return false"` for button, the page stopped post back but the event also stopped working.

I have an option to save the values of controls in view state then recreating the controls and then refill the values to dynamic controls. This option will increase my line of execution.

Is there any other method though which I can prevent the page to post back on asp control event so that my asp control persists with entered values in it and also my event will work.
[this is the Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmOMZ.png)
[this is the Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHWUF.png)

Comment: where is the code you have written in VB.NET?

Comment: Can you provide an example of 1 of these controls, how it's created and the conditions?

Comment: click the links at the end of my question

Comment: Sr28 please suggest something

Comment: Try wrapping the controls you need to update in an updatepanel. That way you don't get a full postback and your controls will persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used JavaScript and Ajax to achieve my requirement.

I have called JS function for button's onclick and Textbox's onchange (like: btn1.Attribute.Add("onClick",JSFunction(); return false;) [return false is to prevent postback].
Then I used ajax post method to do my stuff on .vb page.

Answer (score 0):

Create your dynamic controls OnPreInit Event of Page, Hope this solves your problem

```
override protected void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDynamicControls();//Function which creates all dynamic controls

    }
```